# Twiki default editing mode

Tags: twiki

When editing pages in TWiki I prefer to edit in wiki markup mode, not the default HTML.

- How do I set this preference?
- Is it possible on a per-user basis?

Answer (score 2):

you can set the NOWYSIWYG setting (mmm, that might be a http:://foswiki.org improvement the older one was called something cryptic like TINYMCEPLUGIN_DISABLE), either in the Site, Web or user preference.

Answer (score 0):

You can [set preferences](http://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/TWiki/TWikiVariables#Preferences_Variables) on a per-user basis like this:

```
---++ My Personal Preferences

   * Preference for the editor, default is raw editor, The options could be rawedit, wysiwyg.
      * Set EDITMETHOD = rawedit
```

Copy this snippet to your user page.

I can't remember how I figured this out; there wasn't a super obvious way to do it. Maybe I just trolled through [the preferences page](http://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/TWiki/TWikiPreferences) until I found the right option to override.